# Removing all binary variables from the data

Tags: r, binary, dummy-variable

I have data as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3), B=c(1,0,1), C=c(0.1, 0.011, 0.3), D=c(0, 0.5, 1))

  A B     C   D
1 1 1 0.100 0.0
2 2 0 0.011 0.5
3 3 1 0.300 1.0
```

Ho can I remove all binary variables (= `B`) from this data.frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Filter(function(x) !all(x %in% c(0, 1)), df)
```

Output:

```
  A     C   D
1 1 0.100 0.0
2 2 0.011 0.5
3 3 0.300 1.0
```

Note: you could also add `NA` to `c(0, 1)` if needed.

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% select(!where(~all(.x %in% 0:1)))
  A     C   D
1 1 0.100 0.0
2 2 0.011 0.5
3 3 0.300 1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option for fun,
We can also explicity search for each value (as @Allan Cameron mentions), i.e.

```
df[colSums(df ==1 | df == 0) != nrow(df)]

#  A     C   D
#1 1 0.100 0.0
#2 2 0.011 0.5
#3 3 0.300 1.0
```

Comment: maybe `%in%` instead of `==` or `df == 1 | df == 0`

Comment: @AllanCameron `%in%` does not work. The `or` operator does on the other hand

Comment: @Sotos, Great option! Is it also possible if `NA` is needed?

Comment: This is incorrect. it works because of vector recycling. And you know that. for example, try `df1 <- rbind(df, 1)` and now try `df1 == c(0,1)` and see what happens